# WCF STS Token Expiration Problem

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, sts-securitytokenservice

I have a WCF service (FooService) protected by Secure Conversation. Also have an STS (StsService) that provides tokens to clients calling FooService. The tokens are good for 15 minutes. The STS is custom-build (no Geneva). The client also has some custom WCF extensions to allow re-use of the token across several services during the lifetime of the client.

The client requests a token from the STS when "Open" on the channel to FooService is called. The STS works fine, issues the token and provides a valid RSTR back to the client. The client receives the de-serialized token (as a `GenericXmlSecurityToken` object).

**Problem:**

When the client receives the `GenericXmlSecurityToken` instance, the expiration date is NOT set correctly. In the RSTR, there is a SAML tag `<saml:Conditions>` which has the valid expiration date BUT, for some reason, WCF does not seem to be parsing the tag and using the value of `NotOnOrAfter`.

Here is the binding for the STS (server-side):

```
    <binding name="stsBinding" receiveTimeout="infinite" 
sendTimeout="infinite">
      <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation" requireSecurityContextCancellation="true">
        <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="23:59:59" />
        <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="23:59:59" 
inactivityTimeout="00:02:00" />
        <secureConversationBootstrap 
authenticationMode="UserNameForSslNegotiated">
          <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="23:59:59" />
          <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="23:59:59" />
        </secureConversationBootstrap>
      </security>
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
```

Here is the client-side binding:

```
<binding name="stsBinding"
     closeTimeout="00:02:00"
     openTimeout="00:02:00"
     sendTimeout="00:02:00">
      <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation" requireSecurityContextCancellation="true">
        <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="23:59:59" />
        <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="23:59:59" 
inactivityTimeout="00:02:00" />
        <secureConversationBootstrap 
authenticationMode="UserNameForSslNegotiated">
          <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="23:59:59" />
      <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="23:59:59" />
    </secureConversationBootstrap>
  </security>
  <binaryMessageEncoding />
  <tcpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152"
                maxBufferSize="2097152" maxPendingConnections="10"
                listenBacklog="10" />
</binding>
```

I have tried several things to get the correct expiration date to show-up... but nothings seems to work. Tried implementing a custom Serializer. Could not find any trace of `<saml:Conditions>`.  Also tried calling the STS directly, then providing the token back to WCF. That solution worked, calling the STS directly and de-serializing the response into a valid SecurityToken, but when it is provided back to WCF, the "Open" call on the channel times-out after 2 mintues. No error message, nothing in the trace log...

On the client-side, the token has the SAML assertion. If I look at: `((GenericXmlSecurityToken)token).TokenXml.InnerXml`, this is what I see:

```
<saml:Conditions 
NotBefore="2009-09-01T19:36:54.669Z" 
NotOnOrAfter="2009-09-01T19:41:54.669Z" 
xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion">
</saml:Conditions>
```

Even tried stepping through the .NET Framework source, but cannot do that with VS 2008 SP1 on Windows 7. DOES NOT WORK! Arg!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try configuring message logging, to check what is actually being sent.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I have configured message logging. The message contains the valid <saml:Conditions> element with a valid NotValidOnOrAfter attribute. It is just getting ignored on the client side.

Comment: That is what I thought, but I tried parsing it manually and it parses into DateTime just fine...

Here is what the client receives from the server:
((GenericXmlSecurityToken)token).TokenXml.InnerXml


== 

<saml:Conditions NotBefore="2009-09-01T19:36:54.669Z" NotOnOrAfter="2009-09-01T19:41:54.669Z" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion"></saml:Conditions>

Comment: In your question you have "NotValidOnOrAfter" in the token it is "NotOnOrAfter", could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, that was a typing mistake.